# Changing Database Schema in the ASP.NET MVC4 Entity Framework Database First Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

I've a ASP.NET MVC4 EF DatabaseFirst Application. It's currently up & running. Now, I will have to make some changes to the Database Schema and re-deploy again. So when I make the DB Schema changes, how do I update the Model, and also which all files should I be updating.

Can someone point me to a tutorial for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an ADO.NET entity data model, open up your `Model.edmx`, right-click anywhere and select `Update Model from Database` in the context menu.

[image: Updating model]

If you've added new tables to the database you'll need to mark the checkbox "Tables" under the `Add` tab. If you've only modified existing tables, you can just press `Finish` straight away.